# postgres 15: function json_typeof(json[]) does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I am on postgres 15 (docker image `postgres:15`, version 14 acts in the same way), and have json arrays in the columns of my tables (not just array or just json fields, but `JSON[]` type, to be specific) yet a whole lot of json array - related functions are missing:

```
ERROR:  function json_array_elements(json[]) does not exist

ERROR:  function json_typeof(json[]) does not exist
```

Why? This should not be the case with such a recent version.

Running this returns an empty result set:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'json'
```

And when I try to install it with `CREATE EXTENSION json;`, I get:

```
ERROR:  extension "json" is not available
DETAIL:  Could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/15/extension/json.control": No such file or directory.
```

Comment: json_array_elements(json) exists, but json_array_elements(json[]) doesn't exist. You can create that one yourself, but do you really need it? Do you have array of json-objects? Not just json, but the ARRAY[json], is that what you try to process?

Comment: I have arrays of JSON objects in the columns of my tables (to answer your question - yes).

Comment: An array of JSON values is not JSON itself though is it? Why would you expect to call JSON functions on it?

Comment: Using `json[]` almost never makes sense. Use `jsonb` and store a JSON array in there (as opposed to an array of JSON which is what you currently have)

Comment: "*yet a whole lot of json array - related functions are missing:*" no they are not. That's a "native array" (of JSON values) which can be used with any [array function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html). If you use a `jsonb` that _contains_ a JSON array, you can use all the relevant [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Comment: There are almost no functions in PostgreSQL that can handle an array, just the array functions. This has nothing to do with json. For example the text function SUBSTRING(), that won't take an array. LOG(numeric) doesn't except an array, etc. You expect something that never existed. The good is you can create these functions yourself. Or fix your data model.

Comment: If you have arrays of JSON objects in the columns of your tables then use `unnest` rather than `json_array_elements` because an array of JSON objects is a Postgres' array rather than a JSON array. Please note that `JSON[]` is not of type JSON.